# What is the single character after a value called/exactly do in C#? (eg 1.00m)

Tags: c#

What is this feature "called" when you add a literal chracter beside the value of certain types?

```
decimal d = 1.00m;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called *suffix*.

From the [MSDN decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) article:

> If you want a numeric real literal to
>   be treated as decimal, use the suffix
>   m or M, for example:

Answer (score 1):

Both uppercase and lowercase suffixes work.

L = long
D = double
F = float
U = unsigned int
M = decimal
UL = unsigned long

Answer (score 0):

```
Type        Suffix    .NET Framework Type                  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
decimal     M or m    System.Decimal
double      D or d    System.Double
float       F or f    System.Single
int         [1]       System.Int32
long        L or l    System.Int64
```